Slow internet Download on my server using wired connection
Recently added a 25G network interface card (NIC), and am connected to my network through fibre but recently I am experiencing extremely slow download speed (5-254 kbps) on my 1Gbit/sec connection.
sudo lshw -c network

Output:
network:0
description: Ethernet interface
product: Ethernet Controller XXV710 for 25GbE SFP28
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:af:00.0
logical name: ens6f0
version: 02
serial: 3c:fd:fe:e7:b1:60
size: 10Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHZ
capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation-off broadcast=yes driver=140e driverversion=2.8.20-k duplex-full firmware=7.10 0x800051ac 19.0.12 ip=192.168.8.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=fibre speed=10Gbit/s
resources: iomemory:39800-397ff iomemory: 39800-397ff irq:400 memory: 398000000000-398000ffffff memory: 398002800000-398002807fff memory:ee680000-ee6fffff m emory:398002000000-3980023fffff memory:398002810000-39800290ffff

network:1
description: Ethernet interface
product: Ethernet Controller XXV710 for 25GbE SFP28
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0.1
bus info: pci@0000:af:00.1
logical name: ens6f1
version: 02
serial: 3c:fd:fe:e7:b1:61
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHZ
capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress ypd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical
configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=i40e driverversion-2.8.20-k firmware-7.10 0x800051ac 19.0.12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes resources: iomemory: 39800-397ff iomemory:39800-397ff irq:400 memory: 398001000000-398001ffffff memory: 398002808000-39800280ffff memory:ee600000-ee67ffff m mory:398002400000-3980027fffff memory:398002910000-398002a0ffff

i dont know how to resolve this, please help?
